# Akka Stream - Timer or Scheduler like CRON

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I use Akka Stream on Scala. **I'd like to set a scheduler which runs on every 24:00**. I tried to search for it. But I could't find what I want to do. Could you tell me how to write code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the build in Akka scheduler, see: 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html

You can use the scheduler like:

```
system.scheduler.schedule(
  initialDelay = FiniteDuration(/*offset to next 24:00*/),
  interval = FiniteDuration(24, TimeUnit.HOURS),
  receiver = self,
  message = ScheduleAkkaStream
)
```

Then in the actor, when the ScheduleAkkaStream is received, run the job

Comment: I don't understand how you can get the ScheduleAkkaStream event in your akka stream? Would it not be simpler to just call Source.tick()

Answer (score 11):

This is mentioned in a comment but should really be the preferred solution using only akka-streams:

```
Source.tick(0.seconds, 24.hours, Done).runForeach { x =>
   //do something   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most commonly used one is akka quartz scheduler:
https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler

This one written by me and has no additional dependencies, a bit more lightweight than using quartz with fewer bells and whistles:
https://github.com/johanandren/akron

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
system.scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(10.seconds, 30.seconds)(
 () => {
     println("Action")
   }
)
```

Comment: I don't think that this what the question meant. It wants to run every 24 hours, according to the accepted answer as well.

Comment: The first parameter means time to start, and the second is time after that it will be repeated.